# Detect Misfire Instruction in Quartz API+Spring

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz API to schedule a job which collects some data from the server.It is sending heartbeat in every 5 minutes.This is my configuration file.

```
<bean id="abcJobDetailBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass"
        value="com.vxl.appanalytix.abc.scheduling.abcStatusUpdateJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="abcStatusUpdate" value-ref="abcStatusUpdate" />
            <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="abcJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="abcJobDetailBean" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/10 * * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="abcJobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When scheduler is not able to send the heartbeat. I want to retry the heartbeat in configurable time(Specified in my configuration file).How to specify the misfire time in configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it with xml. You can do it in your Java class itself.

```
try {
        //--------Some operation-------------------
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JobExecutionException e2 = new JobExecutionException(e);
        // -- some logging operations----
        LOGGER.log("------------InterruptedException-----------" + e);
        e2.setRefireImmediately(true);
        throw e2;
    }
```